# Unmanaged IPictureDisp To Managed Object

Tags: vb.net, dll, unmanaged

I'm working Api call dll for Excel with VB.Net. (Robert Giesecke' s unmanaged exports)
Standard types (numeric, strings) are working. But, when try with object type return error.

Error message is:
"Unknown name. (HRESULT exception returned: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"

My function is (Error is IPictureDisp To Bitmap):

```
Public Function GetTextQR_FromPicture(ByVal pictureDisp As IPictureDisp) As [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String
      'IPictureDisp
      Return _qrDec.decode(New QRCodeBitmapImage(PicHelper.GetPictureFromIPictureDisp(pictureDisp)), Encoding.UTF8)
End Function
```

My helper class:

```
Friend Class PicHelper
   Inherits System.Windows.Forms.AxHost

   Friend Sub New()
      MyBase.New(Nothing)
   End Sub

   Friend Shared Shadows Function GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image As Image) As Object
      Return System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetIPictureDispFromPicture(image)
   End Function

   Friend Shared Shadows Function GetPictureFromIPictureDisp(picture As IPictureDisp) As Image
      Return System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetPictureFromIPictureDisp(picture)
   End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The exception does not seem to have anything to do with the posted code.  It is GetIPictureDispFromPicture() that can easily generate it, if not used correctly in the client code.

Comment: When I register by regasm.exe, function run without error. I think, It must unmanaged/managed conversion with Api call.